# C++ Mysql connection fail

Tags: c++, mysql

I have second one problem with C++ & Mysql, 
App complies correctly, but when I try this i have this message:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/elementari/base# ./appkconnectalpha
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'sql::MethodNotImplementedException' appkconnectalpha main.cpp -L/usr/lib -lmysqlcppconn
what():  MySQL_Connection::setReadOnly()
Aborted
```

Code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <mysql_driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void){
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;


  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306","********","***********");
  con->setSchema("Elem_elems");
  stmt = con->createStatement();
  delete stmt;
  delete con;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you given your program permission to change tables in MySQL?

Comment: In phpmyadmin? Yes I give